# Sort SMS messages in ascending order

Tags: android, sqlite, sms, android-contentprovider

When I query the SMS provider in Android I get the messages in from the older ones to the most recent ones. I am using the following query:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri,null,null,null,null);
```

Is it possible to sort it the opposite way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to transform the last argument from `null` to `date ASC`:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri,null,null,null,"date ASC");
```